# Geodesic and Acceleration

Tags: differential-geometry, acceleration, geodesics

The following is from Elementary Differential Geometry by Pressley. He says

> "A bug living in a surface and traveling along a curve $\gamma$ would perceive only the component of
> acceleration parallel to the tangent plane and so would argue that $\gamma$ is a straight line if this component of acceleration is zero everywhere."

Why is this so? If I travel in a car would I feel only the tangential component of acceleration?

Comment: this is locally true, but the tangential plane changed as soon as you move on the surface, thus the straight line is only local